# Get specific columns having with() function in laravel

Tags: laravel

Category Model definition is:

```
class Category extends Model
    {
        public $implement = ['@RainLab.Translate.Behaviors.TranslatableModel'];
        public $translatable = ['name'];
    
        /**
         * @var string The database table used by the model.
         */
        public $table = 'shop_category';
    
        /**
         * @var array Validation rules
         */
        public $rules = [
        ];
        public $attachOne = [
          'icon' => 'System\Models\File'
        ];
    
          public $hasMany =[
            'shops' => ['ItScholarBd\Api\Models\Shop', 'key' => 'shop_category_id']
        ];
    }
```

I want to get category with shop. It works fine if I retrieve all columns but if I try to retrieve specific column it is not working. I want to get only the following columns:
`id, name` of each table. I also apply a condition where `Shop.status = 1`. I am trying as follows:

```
   $this['categoryWithShop']  =   Category::select('id,name')->with(array('shops'=>function($query){
            $query->where('status','=',0);
            $query->select('id','name');
    }))->get();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $this['categoryWithShop']  =   Category::select('id,name')->with(array('shops'=>function($query){
        $query->where('status','=',0);
        $query->select('id','name', 'status');
}))->get();
```

In select query you need to pass that all columns which is needed in query.

Comment: getting this error:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id,name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `id,name` from `shop_category`)  But it actually exist: https://prnt.sc/vms5k4

Comment: You have added select wrong on category. Check this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#specifying-a-select-clause.

Answer (score 0):

try this chaining method and `select('id,name')` this is wrong you need to fix this as `select('id','name')`

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selects

```php
$this['categoryWithShop']  =   Category::select('id','name')->with(['shops' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'name')->where('status', '=', 0);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. Now no error. But shops array is empty. even if I remove the where clause shops array is always empty.